# Dirichlet Convolution

Tags: number-theory, dirichlet-convolution

I was wondering how to simplify the expression: $id \ast (\mu\phi)$, where $\ast$ denotes Dirichlet convolution, $\mu$ is the Mobius function, $\phi$ is the Euler's totient function and $id$ is the identity function. Juxtaposition represents pointwise multiplication.

Comment: Why would that expression be important or interesting?

Answer (score 3):

$$\left(\text{id}*(\mu\varphi)\right)(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}\frac{n}{d}\mu(d)\varphi(d)$$
is a multiplicative function and
$$\left(\text{id}*(\mu\varphi)\right)(p^k)=p^k\sum_{d\mid p^k}\frac{\mu(d)}{d}\varphi(d)=p^k\left(1-\frac{p-1}{p}\right)=p^{k-1}$$
hence we simply have
$$\left(\text{id}*(\mu\varphi)\right)(n)=\frac{n}{\text{rad}(n)} $$
where $\text{rad}(n)=\prod_{p\mid n}p$.